# A proof on sine and being uniform; does it work?

Tags: uniform-continuity

$sin(x)$ is continuous, so it is uniform on closed and limited intervals. Let this interval be $I = [0,3\pi]$, so there exists a $\delta_0$ for a given $\epsilon$.

Then, let us consider all $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. We can assume $y \le x$, and I claim $\delta = \pi$ will work (assuming that the $\delta_0$ does not work).

Since we want to take use of sine's period, I want to express $x,y$ in terms of $2k\pi$. So we can say that $2k\pi \le y \le 2k\pi + 2\pi \Rightarrow 2k\pi \le y \le x \le 2k\pi + 3\pi$. Rewrite to $$0 \le x- 2k\pi \le y-2k\pi \le 3\pi$$
Then set $a = x- 2k\pi$ and $b = y - 2k\pi$, and these are members of $I$ so sine at $x,y$ is equivalent to sin at $a,b$ who are less than $\epsilon$ apart if $\delta$ is 1 or $\delta_0$ (the smaller one is chosen).

does above work, or have I made some mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Much simpler, in my opinion:

$$\left|\frac{\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}\right|=|(\sin c)'|=|\cos x|\le 1\implies |\sin x-\sin y|\le |x-y|$$

What theorem was used? Observe that the above works **for any** $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$

Comment: I'm just trying to "copy" a similar proof, and have used it one sine, so the issue is not to prove sin(x) is uniform, but to prove is using that particular proof.... does it make sense, or do you think I made a mistake?